# how do I obtain all the elements of a generator expression I wrote?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

I am  using google-app-engine webapp, part of the code is :

```
class Post(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    def categories(self):
        return (x.category for x in self.postcategory_set)

class Category(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class PostCategory(db.Model):
    post = db.ReferenceProperty(Post)
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(Category)


class sss(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    obj1 = Post(title='hhaa')
    #obj1.title = 'haha'
    obj1.put()

    obj2 = Category()

    obj2.name='haha-kao'

    obj2.put()
    obj3=PostCategory()
    obj3.post=obj1
    obj3.category=obj2
    obj3.put()
    self.response.out.write(obj1.categories().get().name)
```

but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 511, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "D:\zjm_code\helloworld\a.py", line 131, in get
    self.response.out.write(obj1.categories().get().name)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'get'
```

so how can I obtain all values of the genexp I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted an `all` method you should return a list comprehension instead of a generator:

```
return [x.category for x in self.postcategory_set]
```

but since `postcategory_set` is already an iterable (because you iterated it)

```
return self.postcategory_set
```

would be more natural, but that would give the caller a reference to your private, mutable data, except in this case `Post.postcategory_set` is [not really a `set` type](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) but rather an instance of [`google.app.engine.ext.db.Query`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query) which is indeed iterable but not mutable.

And you didn't ask, but your model is funny, with the PostCategory table being unnecessary when you could have:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    category = db.ReferenceProperty(Category)
    def categories(self):
        return list(self.postcategory_set)
```

And drop `PostCategory` completely.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use "list(self.postcategory_set)" - this will iterate over the related entities, doing fetches in batches of 20. Instead, use self.postcategory_set.fetch(some_num), which returns a list.

Comment: @Nick: agreed, thanks for the clarification. I was trying to work in the context of the OP; that context isn't "best practice" but it also appears that the OP is just learning and working with toy databases.

Comment: Absolutely- I recognized the context, just wanted to point out that there's a better domain-specific solution available.

Answer (score 1):

It is `categories().next()` that you need. Generators have no `get`.